# Showing MWE online

Tags: feature-request, mwe

It would be great, if the MWE (and a special tag (?) for this) would create a document in some online LaTeX, like [WriteLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/) or [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/).

Like it is done on [en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (see the `run this code` button).

Comment: This would need 'back end' changes: not something we (TeX-SX) can do.

Comment: Does this belong to Meta.SE? I'll duplicate it there. This would be really useful feature.

Comment: Not really: my point is that only the Powers can answer. As it's site-specific it still belongs here rather than meta.SE.

Comment: This was discussed previously on meta in [this post](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/link-to-online-latex-compiler?rq=1) - we'd be happy to help support it, but like Joseph Wright says we'd need to work with the SE developers. For reference, our API documentation is provided [here](https://www.writelatex.com/devs)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers SX might add support LaTeX and friends, in the future.